# Bool user preference not changing with simple-prefs using addon SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a preference in my mozilla addon which is of type `bool`, however when the user change the preference this is not relected when accessed from within javascipt ..

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "myaddon",
     ..
     "preferences": [
      {
          "name": "extensions.myaddon.datestamp",
          "title": "Date stamp?",
          "description": "Add date to saved file name",
          "type": "bool",
          "value": "true"
      }]
}
```

main.js:

```
'use strict';
const prefs = require("simple-prefs");

var datestamp = prefs.prefs['extensions.myaddon.datestamp'];
console.log(datestamp);
```

always outputs `info: myaddon: true`, even if preference is not checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with  `"value" :true,` without the doublequotes.